Finding the Second-order sections representation of the IIR filter in C#
I was given a small amount of python code that quickly Calculates and returns a representation of the second-order sections of an IIR filter.
    from scipy.signal import butter
    
    # Parameters
    order = 1
    sample_count = 2048  # Hz 2048
    burst_length = 1650  # samples 1650
    nyquist = sample_count / 2  # Nyquist frequency
    
    
    # Get SOS coefficients
    cutoff = 0.01 * nyquist
    sos = butter(N=order, Wn=cutoff, btype='high',fs=sample_count, output='sos')
    print("SOS Coefficients 1:")
    print(sos)

This prints an array, which is a value i can use in an IIRFilter [0.9845337085968967, -0.9845337085968967, 0.0, 1.0, -0.9690674171937933, 0.0]
if i use MathNet.Filtering.IIR.OnlineIirFilter
the signal filters correctly using those values with this Methoed
FilterSignalWithButterworth(signal)

  public double[] FilterSignalWithButterworth(double[] signal)
  {
      double[] coff = [0.98453371, -0.98453371, 0.0, 1.0, -0.96906742, 0.0];
      var filter = new MathNet.Filtering.IIR.OnlineIirFilter(coff);

      var filteredSignal = filter.ProcessSamples(signal);
      return filteredSignal;
  }

Question
Is there a way to calculate the second-order sections of an IIR filter using .Net?
